# Specific GUI tool to test DB Query/Procedure

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface, jdbc

My web application relies heavily on DB as normal..However using DB queries and DB procedures inside the code often throw up unexpected results. Problems usually arise in queries or DB procedures written by DBA. 
These problems come all the way inside the application whereby we take lot of time figuring out whether the problem lies in application code or Db query/procedure.

We are using MySQL DB and JDBC connectivitiy.

I want to know whether there is any tool where I can check DB query/procedure before using it in application.
Basically a GUI tool where I just need to enter the value for parameters in query/procedure once and then it can run it multiple times with different values which are automatically generated depending upon the datatype...

I don't know is there any such tool available to test DB Query/Procedure...

Answer (score 0):

You may choose SQLYog for your purpose. Also Toad may be the another good option.See the references below :

1. [SQLYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/)
2. [Toad](http://toadworld.com/Downloads/ToadforMySQLFreeware/tabid/561/Default.aspx)

Comment: We already use SQLYog in our application..What I am looking at is something on the lines of SOAPUI or similar kind of stuff where I just need to write query once and then it can automatically fire those queries for different values..I have also explored DB Solo 4 but its on similar lines with SQLYog..

Comment: OK then you may try to create `prepare statement` queries. and then supply values externally.